# Why does this PageReference take me to the wrong page?

Tags: visualforce, pagereference

Given a "save" method such as this:

```
public PageReference save() {

    try {
        insert current_search;
    } catch(System.DMLException e) {
        ApexPages.addMessages(e);
        return null;
    }

    // After successful Save, navigate to the page that shows SearchResult__c objects that are children
    // of this Search__c. 
    PageReference redirectSuccess = new PageReference('/apex/SearchResult/' + current_search.Id);
    return (redirectSuccess);
}
```

I expect to end up at URL that looks like this:

https://na35.visual.force.com/apex/SearchResult/a0041000001QFAAO

but instead I end up here:

https://na35.visual.force.com/apex/a0041000001QFAAO

and I see the message:

Page a0041000001QFEmAAO does not exist

How do I redirect to here?

https://na35.visual.force.com/apex/SearchResult/a0041000001QFAAO

Comment: Is the current code saved as with searchresult in the pagereference

Comment: Is that even valid? Shouldn't it be `?id=a00...` instead of `/a00...`?

Comment: are you sure the save() method is getting called and there is not another place where the redirecturl is being populated?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The "apex" resource URL ignores path names, and only uses the last file name on the path. I tested this in my org with:

```
/apex/pages/TestPage
```

And it resolved to:

```
/apex/TestPage
```

I actually didn't know about this behavior before, and I certainly wouldn't depend on it, but you definitely need to use a parameter instead of part of the file path:

```
PageReference redirectSuccess = new PageReference('/apex/SearchResult?id=' + current_search.Id);
```

Comment: And it has to be the fox who answers such oddities in the platform

Comment: Sounds like my hunch was right. Interesting finding.

Comment: @AdrianLarson Surprising, really. I don't think I've ever intentionally tried to break /apex/ before, but there we have it. Always something new to learn in Salesforce.